# Returning a scalar object

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is there any way in cosmos db to return a scalar object instead of an array?

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.VesselId=40
```

returns:

```
[
    {
        "VesselId": 40,
        "LatestReportId": null,
        "Name": "xxx",        
    }
]
```

I want:

```
{
    "VesselId": 40,
    "LatestReportId": null,
    "Name": "xxx",        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `SELECT top 1 c FROM c where c.VesselId=40` or `SELECT top 1 VALUE c FROM c where c.VesselId=40`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Above query still returns an array, but with only one element in array. I want the first value in the query. Like FirstOrDefault in linq.